# String Concatenation with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So far, I've been trying to make a photo album with different tabs as different albums. To make it work, I used **href** (as suggested) to link the actual tab (button) with the content but it hasn't been working out for me. My album has to be dynamic so the **#albumID** inside **href** has to be dynamic as well.

this is the code. I'm positive the error lies within **href** here.

```
var newTab = $('<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id=newTabID data-toggle="tab" href="'#' + albumName" role="tab" aria-controls=albumName aria-selected="true">Album</a></li>');
```

it should theoretically link to a **div** with ID *albumName*

I know this might sound annoying as it had been asked several times already, but the answers I've found haven't worked for me or is too difficult for me to understand (since question is not exactly alike).

Comment: Yes, you've gone wrong with your quotes in that string. But it's much better in general, when inserting HTML elements, to work with the elements themselves, using the DOM to access/modify attributes and children, rather than just inserting a long string of raw HTML. One reason is you avoid "quote headaches" like this one.

Comment: `var newTab = $('<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id=newTabID data-toggle="tab" href="#' + albumName + '" role="tab" aria-controls=albumName aria-selected="true">Album</a></li>');`

Comment: Try this `var newTab = $('<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id=newTabID data-toggle="tab" href="#${albumName}" role="tab" aria-controls=albumName aria-selected="true">Album</a></li>');`

Comment: If you're using any sort of IDE and not just a text editor, then it will highlight exactly where your error is, as it does here on SO in your code in the question.  Use `\'` or `\"` to escape quotes where you need them, but that's not the case here.

Comment: Thank you! Both of the codes work. I'm only using notepad++ and I'm just so unfamiliar using quotes like these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var newTab = $('<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id=newTabID data-toggle="tab" href="#' + albumName+ '" role="tab" aria-controls=albumName aria-selected="true">Album</a></li>');
```